# SQL - Count Distinct

Tags: sql, dbeaver

Estou tentando fazer o relacionamento de duas tabelas: uma de Clientes e uma de Recargas.

Já criei faixas de recarga, quantidade de total de transações, tipo de transação (Recarga ou Estorno), e informo o período que quero extrair...
Porém, preciso identificar qual é o número de clientes distintos que tenho nesse resultado:

```
    SELECT C.PERSON_TYPE AS TIPO_PESSOA_PF_PJ,
        COUNT(DISTINCT AC.ID) Nro_Of_Dist,
        date_format(TH.IMPUTATION_DATE,'yyyyMM') AS DATA_DE_IMPUTE_CYBERO,
        date_format(TE.EVENT_DATE,'yyyyMM') AS DATA_DO_EVENTO,
        PT.SHORT_DESC AS FORMA_PAGAMENTO,
        AC.NEMOTECNICO AS ATIVIDADE,
        SUM(TH.AMOUNT) AS VALOR,
        COUNT(TH.AMOUNT) as Qtde,
       IF(TH.AMOUNT <=50,"Ate 50",if(TH.AMOUNT <=75,"De 50 a 75",if(TH.AMOUNT <=100,"De 75 a 100",if(TH.AMOUNT <=150,"De 100 a 150",if(TH.AMOUNT <=200,"De 150 a 200",if(TH.AMOUNT <=500,"De 200 a 500",if(TH.AMOUNT <=1000,"De 500 a 1000",if(TH.AMOUNT <=2000,"De 1000 a 2000",if(TH.AMOUNT <=5000,"De 2000 a 5000","Acima de 5000"))))))))) as FaixaRecarga,
        SP.LONG_DESC AS PLANO,
        TE.COMMENTS3 AS CANAL_FORMA_DE_PAGAMENTO
FROM Veloe.ACTIVITY AC INNER JOIN Veloe.TRANSACTION_REASON_ACTIVITY TA ON ( AC.ID = TA.ACTIVITY )
                                INNER JOIN Veloe.TXN_HIST TH ON ( TA.TRANSACTION_REASON = TH.TRANSACTION_REASON )
                                INNER JOIN Veloe.ACCOUNT A ON ( TH.ACCOUNT = A.ID )
                                INNER JOIN Veloe.CUSTOMER_OPERATION CO ON ( A.SUBPRODUCT = CO.SUBPRODUCT AND A.BRANCH = CO.BRANCH AND A.CURRENCY = CO.CURRENCY AND A.OPERATION_ID = CO.OPERATION_ID )
                                INNER JOIN Veloe.CUSTOMER_OPERATION_TYPE TP ON ( CO.TYPE = TP.ID )
                                INNER JOIN Veloe.CUSTOMER C ON ( CO.CUSTOMER = C.ID )
                                LEFT JOIN Veloe.ADDRESS B ON ( CO.CUSTOMER = B.CUSTOMER )
                                --LEFT JOIN Veloe.LOCALITY D ON ( B.LOCALITY_ZIP_CODE = D.ID )
                                LEFT JOIN Veloe.PROVINCE_CODE E ON ( B.PROVINCE_CODE = E.ID )
                                LEFT JOIN Veloe.PAYMENT_TYPE PT ON ( A.CNT_STOP_PAYMENTS_YTD = PT.ID )
                                INNER JOIN Veloe.SUBPRODUCT SP ON ( A.SUBPRODUCT = SP.ID )
                                INNER JOIN Veloe.TXN_HIST_EXT TE ON ( TH.ID = TE.TXN_HIST )
WHERE AC.NEMOTECNICO IN ('RECARGA_MANUAL','RECARGA_AUTOMATICA','ESTORNO_RECARGA_AUTO','ESTORNO_RECARGA_MANUAL') -- --- AQUI PRECISA INFORMAR TODAS AS ACTIVITY DE RECARGAS
AND TP.NEMOTECNICO = 'FIRST_HOLDER_PR' 
AND TE.EVENT_DATE >=  '2020-01-01 00:00:00:0' AND TE.EVENT_DATE <=  '2020-06-30 00:00:00:0'
AND B.IS_FOR_CORRESPONDENCE = 1
```

Porém, quando chamo `COUNT(DISTINCT AC.ID) Nro_Of_Dist`, ele me traz a quantidade distinta de clientes na tabela de clientes e não na tabela de recargas.

Comment: Se você está utilizando funções de agregação (SUM, COUNT) não deveria ter a cláusula GROUP BY?

Comment: Sim, sem o group by essa consulta nem deveria funcionar...com o Group by é pra solucionar o problema. Você agrupando pelos campos que não estão em uma função de agregação (SUM, COUNT, AVG, etc.), ele já irá filtrar pra você e deixar apenas os registros distintos.

Comment: Qual é a tabela de recarga?

Answer (score -1):

Olá,

Para realizar os cálculos necessários vocês precisa adicionar um GROUP BY de acordo com os critérios selecionados